# Unity 2022.3 animator priview animation,i can not preview two animation clip completely

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzVew.png)
After the animation reaches this point（red box）, it stops playing the second segment。
I want to know whether the length of the white line indicated by the arrow the duration of the entire animation preview?

animator priview animation,i want to  preview two animation clip completely

Comment: Are you sure you've set the correct motion in the second state?

Comment: I use the same animation in unity 2020,it works,I think it is a bug in unity 2022

Comment: I have found the bug. Issue ID UUM-59080